# how to unregister or destroy $broadcast-ed events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which is `ng-repeat`-ed  5times and when i broadcast an event from service say `fb-delete` then event gets triggered 5times (same as `ng-repeat`-ed times) I have tried it with local directive scope --> `scope.$on('fb-delete', //do something)` and even with root scope `$rootScope.$on('fb-delete', //so something)` it always triggers multiple times.

how can i make sure $broadcast triggers only once even though directives are many?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Function constructor:

```
function foo ()
  {
  /* do stuff once */
  /*...*/ 
  /*...*/ 
  /*...*/ 
  foo = Function;
  }

scope.$on('fb-delete', foo);
```

**References**

- [rootScopeSpec.js: deregistration](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/rootScopeSpec.js#L1797)
- [AngularJS Scope Life Cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle)